# Async threadsafe Get from MemoryCache

Tags: c#, thread-safety, async-await

I have created a async cache that uses .NET `MemoryCache` underneath.
This is the code:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if(parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    if(!_cache.Contains(key))
    {
        var data = await populator();
        lock(_cache)
        {
            if(!_cache.Contains(key)) //Check again but locked this time
                _cache.Add(key, data, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire));
        }
    }

    return (T)_cache.Get(key);
}
```

I think the only downside is that I need to do the await outside the lock so the populator isn't thread safe, but since the await can't reside inside a lock I guess this is the best way. Are there any pitfalls that I have missed?

**Update**: A version of Esers answer that is also threadsafe when another thread invalidates the cache:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if(parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    var lazy = new Lazy<Task<T>>(populator, true);
    _cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, lazy, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire));
    return ((Lazy<Task<T>>) _cache.Get(key)).Value;
}
```

It can however be slower because it creates Lazy instances that never will be executed and it uses Lazy in full threadsafe mode `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`

**Update with new benchmark (Higher is better)**

```
Lazy with lock      42535929
Lazy with GetOrAdd  41070320 (Only solution that is completely thread safe)
Semaphore           64573360
```

Comment: Suppose  a new thread comes with the same key while the first one *awaits* populate. *populator* for the same key will be executed unnecessarily twice.

Comment: you can use a `SempahoreSlim` with count 1, it has asynchronous wait https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah,  that's the downside I'm aware of,  but it's hard to build around since await can't be locked?

Comment: @ned, nice,  will look at that

Comment: So far as I know is the `MemoryCache` thread safe. Or did I miss something?

Comment: The internal methods are, but if you call contains and then Add those are not threadsafe, plus the async populator is not threadsafe at all even with my above code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) instead of a lock, and then you could get around the issue of awaiting inside a lock. Although, all other methods of `MemoryCache` are thread-safe.

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async Task<T> GetAsync(
            string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if (parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    if (!_cache.Contains(key))
    {
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            if (!_cache.Contains(key))
            {
                var data = await populator();
                _cache.Add(key, data, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }

    return (T)_cache.Get(key);
}
```

Comment: Yes but the contains key check and then insert into cache is not

Comment: Nice solution, Ned was also on the same track

Comment: But there is a bug ;) The populator execution must be inside the if block, otherwise the semaphore solution is no better than my solution above

Comment: What if the moment after you check `!_cache.Contains(key)` but before you do `return (T)_cache.Get` the item gets deleted from the cache due to the expiration policy? The former should be `AddOrGetExisting`. Actually you have the same issue with the inner `_cache.Contains(key)` too.

Comment: @OhadSchneider By former you means the check for `Contains`? It's definitely a possibility that the key would expire prior to the `Get` call.

Comment: Yes I mean both `_cache.Contains` calls. On one hand your method provides "GetOrAdd" semantics (should be renamed really), but on the other hand in some edge cases it does not. Moreover, it would return `null` in those cases, which would be indistinguishable from an actual value of `null` for that key in the cache.

Comment: @OhadSchneider You're right. The main focus of my answer wasn't to redefine the semantics of the call made by the OP, but to show how it's possible to use `SemaphoreSlim` to use in conjunction with an async call. I'll reiterate the code to tackle the expiry issues.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I was wrong in my last observation - you can't add null items to a memory cache, possibly due to the the ambiguity reason I mentioned (of course, it is not documented anywhere, you just get an `ArgumentNullException`).

Comment: The nice thing about this implementation is that the expiration can be a function of the populator's result. For example if the latter gets a token from some service, you could set the cache expiration to the token's expiration.

Comment: This isn't a solution. Every time the cache is called it may have to await other calls. What if you are trying to cache multiple pieces of data? You might find that one thing takes 100 milliseconds, but it keeps having to wait for things that take 2-3+ seconds.

Comment: @ChristianFindlay I'm not sure what you mean by "this isn't a solution". It definitely is a solution, which may perform poorly if you have awaitables that a long time to return. But, same is true for all solutions that internally await. If you care about cache performance, don't make the populator an awaitable, make it pass the value directly.

Comment: It's not a solution because it shares a lock for all the caches. You'd at least need a semaphore for each key (i.e. keep a dictionary of keys) to make this work. Someone else posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65643540/1878141

Comment: @ChristianFindlay It doesn't share a lock for all caches, since there's a single cache. It does share a lock for ALL keys, if that's what you mean. You could implement this more efficiently, yes, but that doesn't make this any less of a solution then the link you pasted here.

Comment: I meant it shares the lock for all cache entries (or keys)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'd say that it performs suboptimally when the cache is handling 2+ entries. That's the typical use-case for a cache, but the OP's question isn't clear if they are wanting to cache multiple entries. I'd not make that assumption though. In most cases, this would be deal-breaker (it is for me). I'd put a caveat though. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 13):

The current answers use the somewhat outdated `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`. They also contain subtle race conditions (see comments). Finally, not all of them allow the timeout to be dependent on the value to be cached.

Here's my attempt using the new [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching) (used by ASP.NET Core):

```
//Add NuGet package: Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory    

using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

public Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(
        string key, Func<Task<T>> factory, Func<T, TimeSpan> expirationCalculator)
{    
    return _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(key, async cacheEntry => 
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cacheEntry.AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(cts.Token));
        var value = await factory().ConfigureAwait(false);
        cts.CancelAfter(expirationCalculator(value));
        return value;
    });
}
```

Sample usage:

```
await GetOrAddAsync("foo", () => Task.Run(() => 42), i  => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i)));
```

Note that it is not guaranteed for the factory method to be called only once (see https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/240).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Answer (score 12):

Although there is an already *accepted* answer, I'll post a new one with `Lazy<T>` approach. Idea is: *to minimize the duration of `lock` block*, if the key doesn't exists in cache, put a `Lazy<T>` to cache. That way all threads using the same key at the same time will be waiting the same `Lazy<T>`'s value

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if (parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    lock (_cache)
    {
        if (!_cache.Contains(key))
        {
            var lazy = new Lazy<Task<T>>(populator, true);
            _cache.Add(key, lazy, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire));
        }
    }

    return ((Lazy<Task<T>>)_cache.Get(key)).Value;
}
```

**Version2**

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if (parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    var lazy = ((Lazy<Task<T>>)_cache.Get(key));
    if (lazy != null) return lazy.Value;

    lock (_cache)
    {
        if (!_cache.Contains(key))
        {
            lazy = new Lazy<Task<T>>(populator, true);
            _cache.Add(key, lazy, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire));
            return lazy.Value;
        }
        return ((Lazy<Task<T>>)_cache.Get(key)).Value;
    }
}
```

**Version3**

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> populator, TimeSpan expire, object parameters)
{
    if (parameters != null)
        key += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

    var task = (Task<T>)_cache.Get(key);
    if (task != null) return task;

    var value = populator();
    return 
     (Task<T>)_cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, value, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire)) ?? value;
}
```

Comment: With your new pattern you can get rid of the lock entirely by dropping the `Contains` check and switching the the `Add` call to `AddOrGetExisting`.

Comment: With Scotts additon its even thread safe when removing entries (Wich not mine nor Yuvals is)

Comment: @Anders I tried it after Scott's comment, but it requires unnecessary Lazy's (although they are not evaluated) be created. So I didn't post it.

Comment: True, also a Lazy set to full thread safe mode is alot slower than  Yuval's solution

Comment: @Anders Also no need for async/await :)

Comment: Did a bench, your version is slowest actually

Comment: @Anders I changed the code a little bit, and my results are not similar to yours. Can you test also the *version2*

Comment: Version two is much faster then Semaphore. Version of that that only uses thread saftly of MemoryCache is this http://pastebin.com/ggfxqGkp My test looks like this btw http://pastebin.com/FSjayVXz

Comment: @Anders One more optimization can be done. Just drop all Lazy's. *Task.Result* (or await) is thread safe. See Version3.

Comment: @Eser thats just test code actually, hmm, which makes the test bad. How can I execute the result in a manner that Web API does for more correct test?

Comment: @Anders Yes, Sorry for disturbance.

Comment: Versions 1 and 2 suffer from a race condition where the item gets cleared right before you return it using `_cache.Get`.

Comment: @OhadSchneider Your edit revision 9 of the code for **Version3** has introduced a bug.  The code as you have written it can return `null`, since `AddOrGetExisting` returns `null` in the cases when it _Adds_.  You should rollback that change to revision 8.  @Eser could also do the rollback.  If the goal of the change was to make the code shorter, consider this: `return (Task<TValue>)(_cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, populator(), DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(expire)) ?? _cache.Get(key));`.  (_Although some will argue it is less readable that the original `if` statement._)

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I assumed `AddOrGetExisting` had the same contract as `GetOrAdd` in `ConcurrentDictionary` (which makes much more sense IMO). Anyway, your proposed fix contains a race condition (imagine the value is added but then is then immediately removed before you get to `_cache.Get`) so I fixed it slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old but I hit this recently and I thought I'd leave this answer hoping it helps.

With async, there are few things to keep in mind:

1. An "uber lock" approach is not quick as it blocks the factory operations on *other* keys when performing one on a key.
2. A "lock per key" (`SemaphoreSlim`) has 2 things going on: a. It's disposable, so disposing it after could race. b. Live with not disposing it.

I chose to solve it using a pool of locks. It's not required to have a lock per key, but just enough locks as the max active threads possible. I then assign the same lock to the key through hashing. The pool size is a function of `ProcessorCount`. The `valueFactory` is executed only once. Since multiple keys map to a lock (a key always maps to the same lock), operations for keys with the same hash will get synchronized. So this loses some parallelism, and this compromise may not work for all cases. I'm OK with this compromise. This is the approach that `LazyCache`, and `FusionCache` (one of its many approaches) use, among other things. So I'd use one of them, but it's good to know the trick though as it's pretty nifty.

```cs
private readonly SemaphoreSlimPool _lockPool = new SemaphoreSlimPool(1, 1);

private async Task<TValue> GetAsync(object key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<TValue>> valueFactory)
{
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
    {
        return value;
    }

    // key-specific lock so as to not block operations on other keys
    var lockForKey = _lockPool[key];
    await lockForKey.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        value = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(key, valueFactory).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return value;
    }
    finally
    {
        lockForKey.Release();
    }
}

// Dispose SemaphoreSlimPool
```

And here's the `SemaphoreSlimPool` impl ([source](https://github.com/rmandvikar/threading/blob/dev/src/rm.Threading/SemaphoreSlimPool.cs), [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/rm.Threading/)).

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Provides a pool of SemaphoreSlim objects for keyed usage.
/// </summary>
public class SemaphoreSlimPool : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pool of SemaphoreSlim objects.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim[] pool;

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of the pool.
    /// <para></para>
    /// Environment.ProcessorCount is not always correct so use more slots as buffer,
    /// with a minimum of 32 slots.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int poolSize = Math.Max(Environment.ProcessorCount << 3, 32);

    private const int NoMaximum = int.MaxValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor.
    /// </summary>
    public SemaphoreSlimPool(int initialCount)
        : this(initialCount, NoMaximum)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor.
    /// </summary>
    public SemaphoreSlimPool(int initialCount, int maxCount)
    {
        pool = new SemaphoreSlim[poolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++)
        {
            pool[i] = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount, maxCount);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="Get(object)" />
    public SemaphoreSlim this[object key] => Get(key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="SemaphoreSlim"/> from the pool that the <paramref name="key"/> maps to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public SemaphoreSlim Get(object key)
    {
        _ = key ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        return pool[GetIndex(key)];
    }

    private uint GetIndex(object key)
    {
        return unchecked((uint)key.GetHashCode()) % (uint)poolSize;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (pool != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++)
                    {
                        pool[i].Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've thrown quite a bit of threads on this with a lot of churn due to low ttl and it's not bombing out. So far it looks good to me, but I'd like to see if anyone can find bugs.

Comment: I don't like this solution. The number of stored entries in a `MemoryCache` is not related to the number of processors in any way. A `MemoryCache` may store thousands of keys, in a machine having 4 cores. What this solution does is to use the same synchronization primitive (a `SemaphoreSlim`) for all different keys that may have the same `key.GetHashCode() % poolSize` value. So the `GetAsync("Light")` may have to wait for the completion of the unrelated `GetAsync("Heavy")`, in case the "Light" and "Heavy" keys happens to have the same hashcode modulo 32.

Comment: Also the `valueFactory` might not be invoked on the current context, because of the `ConfigureAwait(false)`, with unknown consequences.

Comment: Yup, that's a compromise that's ok for me. Cache is typically not write-heavy. All other solutions I seen so far either have a race for valueFactory or live with not disposing, which is worse imo.

Comment: The consuming code can not use ConfigureAwait(false). In my case, I need it.

Comment: Hi, FusionCache creator here: just to be clear, FusionCache does *not* have this contention problem, since it's not using the same lock (SemaphoreSlim) per multiple keys, but it has a 1.1 approach.

Comment: @JodyDonetti What do you mean by "1.1 approach"? This thread is old, and my answer is outdated. If you want, I can update it. What I meant is that FusionCache uses a pool of objects trick, not pool of `SemaphoreSlim`s (last I had check, it was a constant size of ~8k object locks). See https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/blob/d1a36c287e40b160396672bf0905c8eb1d0a573b/src/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/Locking/StandardMemoryLocker.cs#L42. I chose, sometimes, to lock on an object from a pool of objects just to create a task, and await the task outside of the lock.

Comment: In your answer (not comment) there's a pool of SemaphoreSlim, so I was commenting on that.

In FusionCache there' is not such pool, and the pool that is there is just for when a new SemaphoreSlim will need to be created the first time: in the end it's always one SemaphoreSlim per key (and that was the "1:1" part which I wrote wrongly as "1.1").