# c# memoryCache access new value when inserting to cache

Tags: c#, caching, c#-4.0, memorycache

I have this following code block, which is receving a sessionId and need to return the related userId.

```
private static async Task<string> AddOrGetExisting(string sessionId, Func<Task<Tuple<string, DateTime>>> factory)
{
      var newValue = new Lazy<Task<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>(factory);
      var oldValue = _cache.AddOrGetExisting(sessionId, newValue, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = (await newValue.Value).Item2 } ) as Lazy<Task<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>;
      try
      {
          return (await (oldValue ?? newValue).Value).Item1;
      }
      catch
      {
          _cache.Remove(sessionId);
          throw;
      }
}
```

Whenever I store a session, i want the cache to store it only until it expires.

The tuple contains the (string)`UserId` and (DateTime)`ExpirationDate`.
The problem with what I wrote is that im invoking the factory all the time which fetches the data from the datebase which is kinda ruin the whole idea of cache.

How can I access the value only after/if it was retreived?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the expiration time is dependent on the calculated value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831860/async-threadsafe-get-from-memorycache and https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/338.

Comment: BTW the first line and the try/catch clause are redundant. And you should use a direct cast here, not `as`.

Comment: An exceltion may be thrown, such as TaskCancelled or memory access issues or whats more important, my factory might throw one. Are you absolutly sure it is redundant? I have gotten any exception there, yet.

Comment: In your second line (just before `try`) you already evaluate the expression `(await newValue.Value).Item2`. And like I said `oldValue` will never be null so the expression in your try block is equivalent to  `(await oldValue.Value).Item2`. But when you put `oldValue` in the cache the first time it was `newValue`, meaning it was the same expression. If it didn't throw then, it won't throw now...

Comment: although the question is old, this was really the question :) how can i make the expiration as the value. but i did it in a 3-phase thing. get oldvalue, if none get new value and insert with the expiration i have.

Comment: You might want to answer (and probably accept) your own question.