# async-await method (Wait for response)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, memorycache

I use async method follow this code:

```
    public string TryForGetToken()
    {
        cache = getCache;
        if (!cache.Contains(keyToken))
        {
            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            TryForLogin();
            cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expiredTime - 60);
            CacheItem item = new CacheItem(keyToken, publicToken);
            //cache.Add(item, cacheItemPolicy);
            return publicToken;
        }
        else
            return cache.Get(keyToken).ToString();
    }
```

and

```
    public async Task TryForLogin()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            AuthenticationData authenticationData = new AuthenticationData() { email = "zzzzzz", password = "zzzzzzzz" };
            ResponseResult result = await httpServiceCaller.PostJsonAsync<AuthenticationData, ResponseResult>("http://sample.com/agent/login", authenticationData, new CancellationToken(), "Login");
            publicToken = result.data.token.access_token;
            expiredTime = result.data.token.expires_in;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

So after call postJsonAsync method and after that don`t fill publicToken
if I use wait for this vs crash and closed. Do you have idea for this ?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: vs crashed in unrelated: instead, result is filled correctly?

Comment: You may find this question interesting: [Async threadsafe Get from MemoryCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831860/async-threadsafe-get-from-memorycache)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply because the `TryForGetToken` finishes before `TryForLogin` assign value to `publicToken` variable. You are not awaiting Task that is returned from TryForLogin method.


You should rewrite `TryForGetToken` to be `async Task<string>` and then `await TryForLogin()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure what are you asking for but it seems you miss awaiting the `TryForLogin` method.

```
 public async Task<string> TryForGetToken()
    {
        cache = getCache;
        if (!cache.Contains(keyToken))
        {
            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            await TryForLogin();
            cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expiredTime - 60);
            CacheItem item = new CacheItem(keyToken, publicToken);
            //cache.Add(item, cacheItemPolicy);
            return publicToken;
        }
        else
            return cache.Get(keyToken).ToString();
    }
```